# Trigger a jenkins build from git using cloudbees and bitbucket

Tags: git, continuous-integration, jenkins, bitbucket, cloudbees

I'm trying to trigger a jenkins build  automatically when i commit to my git repo. I am using a cloudbees jenkins instance and my repo is located at butbucket.

I configured the jenkins service on my bitbucket repo but it doesn't seem to start the build on jenkins. To configure it i've used the following:

```
Endpoint: https://<my-email>:<my-api-token>@myaccount.ci.cloudbees.com
Project name: <my-build-job-name>
Token: <my-token-name>
```

I have properly set up both the cloudbees SSH public key to bitbucket and verified that jenkins does build my project successfully when triggered manually. It doesn't seem to work however when i push changes to my repository.

I have followed the following tutorial: http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Bitbucket

Has anyone managed to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also followed the [CloudBees BitBucket Tutorial](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Bitbucket)
but what I found is that I had skipped a step as it had been in french.

The step was to check (in the Jenkins Configuration) the **Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)** checkbox and ensure that the **Authentication Token** given is the same **Token** that is given to the BitBucket Service. This, as the tutorial says, is where "the magic will occur".

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [this doc](https://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Bitbucket) about intergating bitbucket with jenkins on Cloudbees, but bitbucket don't officially support credentials on service hooks, and this doesn't seem to work for ALL accounts, even I can't tell why it sometimes fails. Cloudbees instance just never receive the notification http request with credentials set.

Maybe a bitbucket plugin would help, as we have for github and gitlab to manage commit hooks.

Comment: I'm honestly amazed how bitbucket wouldn't provide seamless support for that feature. Under these circumstances it definitely can't be a part of our project stack.

Answer (score 0):

I posted a related solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116495/bitbucket-does-not-trigger-jenkins-builds-on-cloudbees/17116496#17116496) for others who happen to land on this page.