# Bitbucket does not trigger Jenkins builds on CloudBees

Tags: cloudbees

I followed the instructions given in the CloudBees [documentation](http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Bitbucket), but my git pushes (at Bitbucket) did not trigger new builds in Jenkins. Roughly,

1. In Jenkins, create a new build project, and select "Trigger builds remotely".
2. Generate an authentication token, then save the project.
3. Obtain API token at `https://<account>.ci.cloudbees.com/user/<your-email>/configure`
4. In Bitbucket, add a Jenkins service with the following options

   - Endpoint: `https://<your-email>:<apitoken>@<account>.ci.cloudbees.com`
   - Token: `<from-step-2>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is probably outdated.

At the "People" section in Jenkins, it appears that there are two users, one named "user", and another named "user@domain.com" (where "user" and "domain" are replaced appropriately by components in your email address.) When I created the build project, it was created under "user", and so "user@domain.com" did not have the rights to trigger a build.

Thus, the correct endpoint should be

```
https://<the-user-portion-of-your-email>:<apitoken>@<account>.ci.cloudbees.com
```

Note that the api token should be obtained from

```
https://<account>.ci.cloudbees.com/user/<the-user-portion-of-your-email>/configure
```

Comment: Note that in the case where your user name IS your email address, you must urlencode your email address, so the resulting url will be something like http://test.user%40example.com:<api_token>@<account>.ci.cloudbees.com

Comment: Is token (in bitbucket's dlg) and apitoken the same? What is module?

Comment: @ChrisLawlor So you mean one should add the whole (url encoded) email, not just <the-user-portion-of-your-email?>?